# jquery onclick event handler not firing

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following code:

```
    $('.removeruleset').on('click', function(){     
    alert('inside');    
            id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');  
           $('#'+id+'').remove();
            update_call_routing_tag();
    });
```

It should be triggered by html that looks like this:

```
<table id="summary">
           <tbody>
              <tr>
                <th>Actions</th>
                <th>Contact Type</th>                  
              </tr>

              <tr id="rulesegment_1">
                <td><input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeruleset"></td>
                <td name="contact_type" class="contact_type" id="contact_type1">Home</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
 </table>
```

The event is not being fired anymore for some reason. 
I'm currently using jquery 1.10.2 -- that's what I get when I do a "console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);"

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

It must have stopped working after I upgraded my jquery lib.  ??? 
in any case, i added the prefix of "document" as suggested in the answer and it works.  I had done the same for other event handlers.. .but must have been distracted and stopped before I finished with all the functions. 
=/
I've also properly declared "id". 
Thanks.

```
    //$('.removeruleset').on('click', function(){       
    $(document).on("click",".removeruleset",function(){         
            var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');  
           $('#'+id+'').remove();
            update_call_routing_tag();
    });
```

Comment: are you using ajax? is `removeruleset` created dynamically? I assume the variable `id` has been declared prior.

Comment: There's no point in getting the id attribute, then  using it to look up the very element you got it from. `.closest('tr').remove()` would do just as well.

Comment: It works: http://jsfiddle.net/VhsDq/

Comment: Is the `.ruleset` present at the time your click handler is attached? If not, then you should be using a delegated handler instead.

Comment: `$('.removeruleset').on('click', function(){` is no different from `$('.removeruleset').click( function(){`. If the element is dynamically created, you have to listen for the click event bubbling up on a parent that is already present on the page when the DOM is ready. A way to do is to listen to the click even on the document, i.e. `$(document).on('click', '.removeruleset', function(){`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
 $(document).on('click', '.removeruleset', function(){     
    alert('inside');    
        id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');  
       $('#'+id+'').remove();
        update_call_routing_tag();
});
```

But your code works ...

Comment: ah... i must have forgot to add the  $(document).on prefix after i upgraded to 1.10.2.  I have it for other dynamically created objects.  Thanks

Comment: Krishna, please see edit 1.  I've taken your suggestion and added the declare.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Two things: you can just use a .click() function and you didn't declare id as a var.

```
$('.removeruleset').click(function(){     
    alert('inside');    
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');  
    $('#'+id+'').remove();
    update_call_routing_tag();
});
```